# invalidating buttons in form until another button is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a windows form- main frame, there is a panal where I have created a group box as login form. I need to keep the buttons in main frame invalidated till the ok button in group box is clicked. please help. this is my first ever C# project.

Comment: this would help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607868/Social-Club-Sample-application-using-WinForms-Csha#Login

Answer (score 3):

Set the buttons `Enabled` property to `false` as their default in the designer. Then in the button click, set their `Enabled` property to `true`.

```
button1.Enabled = true;
button2.Enabled = true;
```

Where `button1` and `button2` are the names of the buttons you want to enable.

Answer (score 0):

If your login must occur before any other actions within your application, I suggest you create another Logon form that is launched before your main form, and the logon success determines whether the program exits or opens the main form.

EDIT: Much like first comment from @Kyle